# When does RMI make TCP connections?

Tags: java, rmi

I have a test program **T** which:

- Acquires a stub for a `Remote` object O from an RMI registry on server **S**
- In hundreds of parallel threads, invokes methods on this object **O**.

I can see that server **S** has many "RMI TCP Connection" threads. I had expected there to be only one, since there is only one stub of **O** on **T**. How does this work?

Comment: Did you see this in a thread dump? Which server is this?

Comment: @ChinBoon I saw it in VisualVM. It's the server which hosts the `Remote` object.

Answer (score 1):

RMI needs a connection per end-point per thread. It pools them at the client end, which in turn causes pooling at the server end as well, so it isn't actually as bad as that, but if you have 1000 threads performing RMI calls at the same instant there will certainly be 1000 connections. They are not multiplexed.

Comment: Ok, then I'll have to reduce the number of threads in the test program, because that does not reflect the actual number of threads in the real client it's supposed to simulate.

Answer (score -1):

RMI is supposed to try-to reuse server sockets and client sockets if possible.

Your case happens when the server socket factories are not equivalent (when equals is performed, the result is false and the connection is established again). Perhaps the stub haven't implemented hashCode and equals, so there's no certain way to know if the socket is available to be used.

Comment: The stub is nothing special, just `UnicastRemoteObject.export`.

Comment: It is the *client* socket factories that have to be equal, not the server socket factories. His case also happens when there are concurrent calls even *with* 'equal' socket factories, and he has 1000 of them. All RMI stubs implement equals() and hashCode() but it is completely irrelevant to this question. "No certain way to know if the socket is available to be used" is meaningless. Downvote.