# When does the RMI connection get created?

Tags: java, rmi

I'm trying to understand how and when the RMI connection gets created in a very simple application.

```
server = new RemoteServer();
registry = LocateRegistry.createRegistry(PORT);
registry.bind("Remote", server);
```

The client part is:

```
registry = LocateRegistry.getRegistry(HOST, PORT);
remote = (IRemoteServer) registry.lookup("Remote");
```

Let's assume that remote has defined some method `doSomething()`. Now, assuming everything is set up properly and working, I am trying to understand when exactly the TCP connections are made.

- Is a connection made when I call `lookup()`, with that same connection getting reused whenever I call `remote.doSomething()`?  If I call `lookup()` a second time, will that create a second connection?
- Or is a new connection created every time I call `remote.doSomething()` and then torn down afterwards?

([This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11416710/when-does-rmi-make-tcp-connections) is somewhat related, but it's talking about multiple threads invoking a call against a single remote object.)

Answer (score 2):

> when the RMI connection gets created

There is no single 'RMI connection', so the question is already ill-formed.

> Is a connection made when I call lookup()

Yes, probably, see below.

> with that same connection getting reused whenever I call remote.doSomething()?

Possibly, see below, if the remote object is on the same host:port as the Registry; otherwise there will definitely be a new TCP connection.

> If I call lookup() a second time, will that create a second connection?

Possibly, see below.

> Or is a new connection created every time I call remote.doSomething() and then torn down afterwards?

Probably not.

None of this is specified, but the Sun/Oracle implementation does client-side connection pooling, under the control of various [RMI system properties](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/rmi/sunrmiproperties.html), specifically `sun.rmi.transport.tcp.threadKeepAliveTime.` By default connections that have been idle for more than 60 seconds are closed. It used to be 15 seconds.